# Whats the applescript syntax for sending arguments?

Tags: cocoa, applescript

I'm following apples applescript example for [scripting parameters](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SimpleScriptingVerbs/Introduction/Intro.html)

I can send the direct parameter no problem using the following syntax

```
tell app "SimpleScriptingVerbs" to do command with args "Im a direct parameter"
```

However I can't figure out the correct syntax for sending the other optional arguments.

The rest of the accepted optional arguments look like this

```
<command name="do command with args" code="SVrbAgCm" description="run a command with a bunch of arguments">
            <cocoa class="CommandWithArgs"/>

            <direct-parameter description="a text parameter passed to the command">
                <type type="text"/>
            </direct-parameter>

            <parameter name="blinking" code="savo" type="boolean" optional="yes" 
                description="a boolean parameter.">
                <cocoa key="SaveOptions"/>
            </parameter>

            <parameter name="preferred hand" code="LRnd" type="preferredhands" optional="yes" 
                description="a parameter using our enumeration.">
                <cocoa key="TheHand"/>
            </parameter>

            <parameter name="prose" code="Pros" type="text" optional="yes" 
                description="a text parameter.">
                <cocoa key="ProseText"/>
            </parameter>

            <parameter name="ivalue" code="iVal" type="integer" optional="yes" 
                description="an integer parameter.">
                <cocoa key="IntegerValue"/>
            </parameter>

            <parameter name="rvalue" code="rVal" type="real" optional="yes" 
                description="an real number parameter.">
                <cocoa key="RealValue"/>
            </parameter>

            <result type="text" description="the direct parameter enclosed in quotes"/>
        </command>
```

What's the correct applescript syntax to send the rest of these arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a parameter's name with a value, like this:

```
tell application "SimpleScriptingVerbs" to do command with args "Something" prose "bla 1" preferred hand Left Hand ivalue 299 rvalue 75.777
```

---

The **application** logs -->

```
proc=-[CommandWithArgs performDefaultImplementation] The other parameters are: '{
    "" = Something;
    IntegerValue = 299;
    ProseText = "bla 1";
    RealValue = "75.777";
    TheHand = 1279816302;
}'
```